# Using PIVOT TSQL command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I tried to playaround with the `PIVOT` TSQL command but I got stuck.

I tried with some minimalistic example I could solve also using aggregate functions (so please don't answer about using `COUNT`), just to understand.

This is the example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [EventType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL
) 
GO

insert into TestTable values ('Meeting', '2013-01-01')
insert into TestTable values ('Meeting', '2012-02-02')
insert into TestTable values ('Review', '2013-01-01')
insert into TestTable values ('Review', '2012-01-01')
insert into TestTable values ('Other', '2012-05-05')
```

could you please tell me the query that uses `PIVOT` in order to have per year and per Type results?
I expect: 1 Meeting in 2013, 1 in 2012, 1 Revview in 2013, ...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you want for the columns headers but the basic PIVOT syntax will be the following.

If you want the years to be column headers, then you can use:

```
select EventType, [2013], [2012]
from
(
    select EventType, 
        date = year(date)
    from dbo.testTable
) d
pivot
(
    count(date)
    for date in ([2013], [2012])
) piv;
```

If you want the EventTypes to be column headers:

```
select year, Meeting, Review, Other
from
(
    select EventType, 
        year = year(date) 
    from dbo.testTable
) d
pivot
(
    count(EventType)
    for EventType in (Meeting, Review, Other)
) piv;
```

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(EventType) 
                    from dbo.testTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT year,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select EventType, 
                  year = year(date) 
              from dbo.testTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(EventType)
                for EventType in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is clear to me. One more note: if i want (from the first example) filter only the 2012 events shuold I put a where condition in thee query or is it possible to do it in pivot too?

Comment: @user193655 If you want to use a WHERE filter, then you would put that in the subquery before you pivot.

Comment: By testing i found one more problem. How to get all EventType listed, so how to avoid to write `in (Meeting, Review, Other)` (refer to your second example). So how to have column headers automatically?

Comment: just to be sure to having expressed myself somehow I need to perform somehting like this: `for EventType in (select distinct EventType from TestTable where EventType <> 'Other')`

Comment: @user193655 You will have to use dynamic sql if the event types are unknown, see my edit

Comment: Thanks, this is veery useful, even if what i suggset would be a nice addition to the `PIVOT` feature. I cannot upvote anymore your answer...

Comment: What an exciting feature! I wonder how many hours i lost in the past becuase i was trying to use aggregaate functinos and TempTables...

Comment: @user193655 You can still use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result. There are database platforms that don't support pivot and they need to use that to convert rows into columns

Comment: Not to keep asking here I made a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659203/how-to-filter-pivot-results

Comment: ... and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660921/transposing-a-a-pivot-query