# How to filter pivot results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

Is it possible to exclude some vaules from the `PIVOT` results.

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656411/using-pivot-tsql-command) i would like to know if it is posible to exclude the columns in the Pivot table that has 0 value.

Imagine there is a count of 0 for EventType Meeting, is it possible not to show it at all?

Comment: It seems answer provided by @bluefeet to your previous question work fine in this case (the part with dynamic query), if no rows with `Meeting` type in the original data, the column is not included in the result.

Comment: I tried the solution and i didn't notice bad results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope you have implemented following solution from the question

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(EventType) 
                    from dbo.testTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT year,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select EventType, 
                  year = year(date) 
              from dbo.testTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(EventType)
                for EventType in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

if so then you can do following

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@where AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(EventType) 
                    from dbo.testTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @where = ' where ' + STUFF((SELECT distinct ' Or ' + QUOTENAME(EventType) + ' <> 0 '
                    from dbo.testTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,2,3,'')

        set @query = 'SELECT year,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select EventType, 
                  year = year(date) 
              from dbo.testTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(EventType)
                for EventType in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ' + @where


execute(@query)
```