# Transposing a a PIVOT query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, transpose

A query that uses `PIVOT` is it transposable?

IN [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656411/using-pivot-tsql-command) i understood how to use `PIVOT` but there are cases in which it would be better to have the columns as records.

THis is achievable by transposing the query resultset. Is it possible?

Comment: if you want the columns as rows, then just don't use a pivot to begin with...

Comment: Are you talking about converting columns back into rows?

Comment: Yes converting baxk to row. The idea is use pivot to have the results and then transpose all. I need this since the query results set goes to a dataset used by a chart component that expects many rows not many columns.

Comment: @user193655 Then don't pivot it in the first place, just select from your table. If that is not what you mean then you will need to edit your question provide data and your requirements.

Comment: Yes of course that is an approach, but anyway it is not transposable or insertable in a Temp Table?

Comment: @user193655 You can use unpivot to convert the columns into rows but that would be absolutely pointless, just leave your data in the original format

Comment: On top of what the others have said, you will be just wasting resources and adding overhead to your query by pivoting the data then unpivoting it.  It will be best to not pivot for this particular query or creating a new query/view/sp etc.. that doesn't pivot the data.

Comment: I think you need to show exactly (as in through data) what you want to achieve. Your question, as stated, was answered with the 1st comment.

Comment: @DataMasseur iamgine the scenario where i have a very complex result set made in pivot. It contains all the data i need. Since i need to make several reports with it i would like to reuse it, not rewwriting new queries. somehow if i could put all in a temp table (as it is doable with a `select into from` statement) it would be great for me. If not we can keep debating about good and bad practices, but often "bad" pracitces are time savers.

Comment: You could refactor the existing PIVOT query so that first you get the results of the complex calculation unpivoted (which you can use where row data are expected), *then*, using a *different* query/view/whatever, you pivot the data so that you can feed them into where pivoted data are needed. You could use a view for the first result set and read that view with the other query to transpose the rows.